# Navigation Drawer - Hide and Show menu item of action bar for fragment and sub fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, navigation-drawer

Create test app using navigation drawer has 3 fragment-
1. fragment1
2. fragment2
3. fragment3

fragment1 has action menu item - search and write

fragemnt2 has action menu item - add and send

fragment3 has action menu item - add and send

If I'm select fragemnt1 then action bar show the menu item - search and write

If I'm select fragemnt2 then action bar show the menu item - add and send

If I'm select fragemnt3 then action bar show the menu item - add and send

But when I'm select the fragment2 the action menu not changed

How can I change the action bar menu item based on fragment?

Answer (score 0):

write below line in onCreateView

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and inflate fragment in onCreateOptionsMenu method like activity